# Get 802.11 frames from remote access point in the same local network

Tags: network-programming, wifi, snmp, access-point

I want to configure all access point in the building  to send the received 802.11 management frames to my server.
and then I am able to save them on my server in order to use them for my location application to track the moving object.

Note:Syslog doesn't  include all the received frames

I am asking:

Is it possible to synchronise the access point with a server to get all the received frames?
Is it possible to read this information periodically by SNMP or Telnet? 
Can you tell me which MIP OID should I requests & get   to retrieve a list of management frames(such as probe request) from Access points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use any capturing technique such as libpcap or RAW socket in monitoring mode and then analyse the radiotap header.